# cplex out of memory 1001 - CPLEX flow control

Tags: cplex, opl

I am trying to solve a complex MILP, however, CPLEX keeps going out of memory (cplex out of memory 1001). This happens because the memory (RAM) allocated to CPLEX is insufficient to store the tree (in branch n bound).

I found a way to move this to the hard drive without terminating the optimizer. I found the syntax to implement this, however, I am not sure how it is used in the flow control. Below is the available list of syntax given in the CPLEX user manual.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/22.1.1?topic=parameters-node-storage-file-switch